# How to make a RecyclerView of EditTexts act as if it were a single EditText

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I'm building an Android app that syntax highlights source code files. Previously, I had performance issues with large files, so my editor is now a `RecyclerView` where each cell contains an `EditText`. While my app is performing great now, unfortunately the `RecyclerView` doesn't always behave like an `EditText`.

In particular, when I hold the `EditText` highlighting the word beneath my finger, and try to drag the slider past the number of lines in the `EditText`, I hit an impasse where I am unable to progress further:

(Sorry, wasn't able to scale the image down)

[image]

In the above image, I can't drag past the end of the highlighted region.

A similar problem happens when I:

- Tap somewhere (without highlighting), and try to drag the slider down
- Hold my finger, then select 'Select All'. Only what's in the current `EditText` is highlighted.

How do I make the `RecyclerView` act as if it's a single `EditText`? Thanks.

Comment: Well… afaici (as far as I can imagine) you can’t do that _this way_ without heavy usage of custom selection and touch detection. In a recycler view, each edit text is exactly that… a different edit text. There’s no such thing as a “merged” selection between different edit texts in Android.

Comment: An alternative could be to allow for “full line” selection, then you can create 1 line rows and let the user “select and drag” the desired lines. You’d lose some functionality (precise selection) but… you’d gain performance (each row is a recycler view row with a line of text) and simplicity.

Comment: you may manage the pop menu yourself

Comment: @MartinMarconcini, I think functionality is more important that perf/simplicity here. I'd be willing to go with a solution that involves "heavy usage of custom selection and touch detection."

Comment: I don’t think you can do what you’re trying to do with a recycler view, without extremely heavy use of custom views that are able to talk to each other (or delegate selection to a common object) and pass it onto the native EditText widgets, but I’m sure that it will be hard/impossible to do with Google APIs. Another approach is to have a single edit text, but only “load” (on demand) as you scroll, both above and below the visible range. This way there’s not a huge text in memory, only parts of it visible at the same time.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Then 'Select All' wouldn't work, would it? Or trying to highlight a region of text taller than the screen...

Comment: Well, I didn’t say it was going to be easy. You’d have to intercept those popups (or provide your own) that “do the right thing” behind the scenes; it may not work, but I guess with a heavily customized view, you could. The problem is that the more custom the less “native” stuff you get “for free”. (It’s a fascinating problem/project, that for sure) ;)

Comment: I stumbled on this topic while looking for something else, and I now wonder if you've ever made this actually happen, or if not, did you ever solve it in any way? Using the RV/multiple EditText combo like this could have some interesting uses, if not this limitation.